# How to setup TYPO3 12 on Laragon?

Tags: typo3, laragon, typo3-12.x

I've installed typo3 12 on Laragon.

Everything was going well until I try to login to TYPO3 for the first time and get this error:

> Unsupported sendmail command flags
> "D:/laragon/bin/sendmail/sendmail.exe"; must be one of "-bs" or "-t"
> but can include additional flags.

What changes in which file do I need to get this working?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have not much clue about hosting TYPO3 on Windows but you could try to change some mail settings in the TYPO3 Install tool. That should be available at `yourdomain.tld/typo3/install.php`.

After the login to the install tool go to Settings => Configure Installation-Wide Options.

There search for `[MAIL][transport_sendmail_command]` and check the values there.

If this doesn't work out, you can go to `[MAIL][transport]` and set it to SMTP (to use any other SMTP server for the mail transport) or use `mbox` to disable sending mails.

As Laragon seems to be a local development tool you can also check if there is a Mailhog implementation available.

Update: If the install tool doesn't work either, you can make all changes manually in `config/system/settings.php` (TYPO3 v12) or `typo3conf/LocalConfiguration.php` (TYPO3 v11 and older). If the array key doesn't exist, just add it. You can see all default values in `vendor/typo3/cms-core/Configuration/DefaultConfiguration.php`.

In case you want to have specific changes only in your development environment but not in production, create the file `config/system/additional.php` (or `typo3conf/AdditionalConfiguration.php`) and change the settings there, e.g. like this: `$GLOBALS['TYPO3_CONF_VARS']['MAIL']['transport'] = 'mbox';`

Side note: I can only recommend [DDEV](https://ddev.com/) as local development environment. It ships out the box with support for TYPO3 and has also Mailhog on board. Since it's Docker based, it comes with Apache or Nginx and helps you to set up a development environment that is very near to your later production environment.

Comment: Ok, so the install tool gives that same error after entering password. and won't let me do anything else. (I don't even want mail functionality, just want to login to the backend of my fresh install)

Comment: I may check out DDEV at some point, but I was reading about how easy Laragon is to work with and wanted to give it a shot.

Comment: Is there a way to set the `mbox` setting manually in a file somwhere?

Comment: Yes, that's possible. I've updated my answer above accordingly.